# WidgetKit - API Calls

Tags: swift, xcode, widgetkit

I am trying to create a widget that can display information about my car. I am currently using API for my main app, but also want to include this in my widget, but haven't found a way to do this.

How can I get value from API, and display the value in the widget? Is this even possible in `WidgetKit`? Should I include the API call inside the `getTimeline` function?

EDIT: This is the code I am using for API call:

```
let apii = TeslaSwift()
    
   if let jsonString = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "tesla.token") as? String,
       let token: AuthToken = jsonString.decodeJSON(),
       let _ = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "tesla.token") as? String {
        apii.reuse(token: token, email: nil)
    }
    
    apii.useMockServer = false
    apii.debuggingEnabled = true
    
    let id = UserDefaults(suiteName: "xxxx")!.string(forKey: "GlobalSelectedID")
    
    apii.getVehicle(id!).done {
        (vehicle: Vehicle) -> Void in
        
        apii.getAllData(vehicle).done { (extendedVehicle: VehicleExtended) in
            
            carState = (extendedVehicle.state!)
            batteryLevel = (extendedVehicle.chargeState?.batteryLevel)!
            interiorTemperature = (extendedVehicle.climateState?.insideTemperature!.celsius)!
            
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss"
            let now = Date()
            let dateString = formatter.string(from:now)
            lastUpdated = dateString
            
        }.catch { (error) in
            
            print("error1: \(error)")
        }
        
    }.catch { error in
        print("error2: \(error)")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can display values in widgets from API.

1. Save data in userdefaults from main app and then retrieve this data from userdefaults in getTimeLine function. You need to use app group for shared userdefaults. You can reload widgets from main app easily after saving data in userdefaults.
2. API call from getTimeLine

Comment: I actually already am using the first way you said, but since the widget should display info about the car, I want it to update automatically, without the user having to open the main app to get the latest info.

Comment: getTimeline calls automatically after some times, so I think API call from getTimeline will be better for your needs.

Comment: Somehow I managed to get value from the API, by adding the API calls insde the `getTimeline`, but the widget doesn't show the values until I run `WidgetCenter.shared.reloadAllTimelines()` from my main app. I want it to show the values without opening the main app. What am I missing?

Comment: It is better to call reloadAllTimelines after parsing data from API in main app. Actually, it calls the getTimeline without opening main app within an hour or more but it calls for sure. You can debug in getTimeline and wait.

Comment: Omg, I made it work! Finally.. Took so long time, but finally. Thanks tho! Giving you a checkmark :)